# replace variable from for loop into a sed command

Tags: shell, sed

I tried the following snippet of code, but the `sed` command replaces with $var explicitly shown rather than as thr value of the var at that time. How can I solve this?s

```
for var in 01 02
do       
sed -e 's/%\\include{removeMe}/\\include{chapter_$var}/g'
done
```

Comment: Can you provide a sample of your input data (btw sed command has missing file name).

Answer (score 2):

Try double quotes:

```
sed -e "s/%\\include{removeMe}/\\include{chapter_$var}/g"
```

(Better still, try single/double quotes with a simpler example first.)

Comment: Yes, the solution is to use double quotes to get the variables expanded.

Comment: @Beta Using double quotes didn't do any replace! The single quotes did the replace of the text but not the substitution on the $var.

Comment: @Beta The problem is the % symbol. Without it it works. But with it, no replace takes place.

Comment: add option --posix or escape % with \%

Answer (score 0):

```
for var in 01 02
 do       
   sed -e "/[%]\(\\include{\}removeMe}/ s//\1chapter_${var}}/g"
 done
```

use the back reference and encapsulation

but it could be replace by if var is not used with a filename association (so sed is a pipe) like in your sample (also because replacement by 01 will remove any possibility of finding a pattern for 02 replacement)

```
YourStream | sed -e 's/%\(\\include{\}removeMe}/\1chapter_01}/g'
```